# Not getting expected output - Finding all subwords of a word

Tags: c, debugging

I am writing code to find all the subwords of a given word. It takes in a WordGame which has a dictionary in its struct (implemented using a tree).

What it's supposed to produce is all the subwords of a word and these subwords are in my aforementioned dictionary. However, say for example the word is "libels", the output is

```
"lib"

"libel"

"libels"

"libs"
```

The code is

```
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void subWords(char *a, int i, int n, WordGame game) 
{

//This algorithm first finds all the anagrams of a 6 letter word.
//For each anagram it then finds all the 3/4/5/6 in the dicitonary.
//To find the 3/4/5/6 letter words it first finds all the 3 letter words
//then the 4 letter words and so on. 
//For example, to find 3 letter words from the word ABCDEF it does this
//  A   B   C   D   E   F 
// |_| |_| |_|             = ABC

// A    B   C   D   E   F
//     |_| |_| |_|         = BCD 

//etc

//Since it does this for all the anagrams of the 6 letter word it should
//find all the 3 letter subwords of the 6 letter word then for the 4 letter
//subwords and so on.

   int j; 
   int k;
   int m;
   if (i == n){ //When an anagram is foumd
    for(k = 3; k <= 6; k++){ //Used for finding subwords of lengths 3-6
        char str[k];
        for(m = 0; m + k <= 6; m++){  //Used for making sure we don't step
            strncpy(str,a+m,k);       //out of array and moving along array
            str[k] = '\0';
            if(DictFindWord(game->dict,str) !=0){ 
                if(ListSearch(game->aWords[k],str) == NULL){
                    ListInsertInOrder(game->aWords[k],str);
                    printf("%s\n",str);
                }
            }                     
        }
    }
   }

   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          subWords(a, i+1, n, game);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); 
       }
   }
}
```

It seems to find subwords of the initial state of the word, i.e l-i-b-e-l-s. It doesn't find bile because it's not in the initial state of the word, my code is supposed to find the subwords of all anagrams and it seems to not find the permutations of the word. This makes it look like my subWord function isn't producing the anagrams of the initial word but this isn't true because when I run my code with this:

```
   int j; 
   if (i == n){ //When an anagram is foumd
   printf("%s\n",a);
   }

   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          subWords(a, i+1, n, game);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); 
       }
   }
}
```

It prints all the possible permutations of the word. The functions ListSearch, InsertInOrder are supplied functions and most likely correct.

NOTE: When I call the function I call the function subWords I call it with n which is one less than the array size so I would not be accessing elements out of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some out-of-bound accesses in your code.

First, your "raw" version, which only prints the permutations, doesn't work for me, because you access element `a[n]`. Array indices include 0, but exclude the array length. A loop like:

```
for (j = i; j <= n; j++) ...
```

where `j` is used to index an array of length `n` should ring some alarm bells. So:

```
} else {
    for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
        swap((a + i), (a + j));
        subWords(a, i + 1, n);
        swap((a + i), (a + j));
    }
}
```

The same goes for your auxiliary array `str`. It holds `k` characters plus the null terminator at the end. You set the null terminator correctly with

```
str[k] = '\0';
```

but for this to work, the char array `str` must have one element more than `k`, otherwise you access the element after the end of the array:

```
char str[k + 1];
```

(The algorithm itself is rather inefficient. For `"libels"`, you end up generating 6! = 720 permutations and then check all 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10 subwords for each permutation. You end up checking some words several times, and not just because your word has two L's.

You could reduce the number of checks by finding the substrings of the original first and then ppermuting the substrings. This will at least guarantee that you don't do multiple checks on one word if the original word has unique letters. For libels, that will reduce your checks to 4·3! + 3·4! + 2·5! + 1·6! = 1054 checks.

If you have to check many words against the same dictionary, even this will be slow. If you could store your dictionary in a way that you can quickly find all words that can be made up of 1b, 1 e, 1 i, 2 l's and 1 s, you could speed up your algorithm.)

Comment: @M Oehm Oh I'm so sorry, when I call the function I actually call it with n which is one less than the array size

Comment: In that case, you must change the condition `m + k <= 6`, which should really be `n` instead of 6, to: `m + k <= n + 1`.

Comment: @M Oehm Yup, n is always passed in as 5 so it's the same thing

Comment: Well, then why pass `n` at all?

Comment: @M Oehm I removed it now